# How to get multiple max column value mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to query tables using join but I can't get success here my tables

```
Score
id    ,  user_id    ,     score  ,   week
1     ,   123       ,      2     ,    1
2     ,   432       ,      2     ,    1  
3     ,   432       ,      3     ,    1
4     ,   123       ,      2     ,    2
```

I want to query top twenty users records on the bases of sum of week 1 and week 2's max total

I want the result should be

```
id      , user_id     , week1score    , week2score
1       ,  123        ,  2            ,  2
2       ,  432        ,  3            ,  0
```

The formula is order by descending sum(max(week1)+max(week2))

Thanks
Inam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this would do

```
SELECT t1.user_id, 
       SUM(week1score) AS week1score, 
       SUM(week2score) AS week2score 
FROM   (SELECT user_id 
        FROM   `table` 
        GROUP  BY user_id) AS t1 
       JOIN (SELECT user_id, 
                    Max(IF(`week` = 1, score, 0)) AS week1score, 
                    Max(IF(`week` = 2, score, 0)) AS week2score 
             FROM   `table` 
             GROUP  BY user_id, 
                       `week`) t2 
         ON t2.user_id = t1.user_id 
GROUP  BY user_id 
ORDER  BY ( SUM(week1score) + SUM(week2score) ) DESC
```

You need a composit index on the following columns

- (user_id,week,score)

Comment: There is a problem that a week can get multiple records like week 1 may have two scores by same user that is 2,3 now what I have to pick is the maximum score that is 3

Comment: I want to order by the sum of maximum record by a user in week 1 + sum of maximum record of  user in week 2. like this sum(max(week1)+max(week2))

Comment: You are awesome man it is working just one thing missing that you order it using SUM(score) I want to order it as sum(week1score+week2score) how can I do this?

Comment: Error Code : 1247
Reference 'week1score' not supported (reference to group function)
(0 ms taken)

Comment: You are awesome sir... hats off for you... Thank you very much I was trying to make it work for about 2 days but can't do that. Thanks again :)